# Calling string from array using loop after onclick function [javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, onclick

I would like to display one of arrays after clicking matching array: for example

- image 1 after clicking will display array 1
- image 2 after click will display array 2:

---

```
var DetailArray = new Array(
            "number 1",
            "number 2",
            "number 3"
        );

function ShowNumber(number) {
 document.getElementById("number").value=  ;
}
```

img src  image 1 calling function: ShowNumber();

and  paragraph when it would be displayed

```
<p id="number"></p>
```

but I don't really know how to make a loop which will take from arrays matching string.

Comment: arrays are numerically indexed, just correlate the image with the index, and then it's a simple matter from there.

Comment: `.value` is for input elements. You can't use it with `<p>`.

Comment: Pro tip: define your array using `[]` instead of `new Array`, which can have unintended side effects in some situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to set the contents of a paragraph or DIV, `value` is for the value of user inputs.

```
function ShowNumber(number) {
    document.getElementById("number").textContent = DetailArray[number];
}
```

Image 1 can then contain:

```
onclick="ShowNumber(0)"
```

to show `number 1`.